# Alien conversione failed, apt-get broken

Tags: alien

so i have Installed jre1.8.0-101 (a converted *.rpm-package).

Now the trouble is: when i run     `sudo apt-get upgrade`, It says me,
there is a broken package and i should reinstall it (which I already tried).

At the top left corner, there is a 'Stop'-Sign, which says, there was an error in  (the package jre1.8.0-101 needs to be reinstalled, but i can't find a package for it.)

i have already tried

dpkg -P --force-all jre1.8.0-101, which works fine, but only for a while.